# Accuracy of learning algorithm drops after averaging features

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, neural-network, bigdata, prediction

I have a huge dataset that I am trying to clean up. Within this dataset I have 6 columns that represent a rating system from 1-10. So the first column rates a person based on attractiveness, the second column based on intelligence, etc.

```
attr1  attr2  attr3  attr4  attr5  attr6
2      5      6      8      7      2
5      9      6      9      7      3
9      8      7      5      8      6
     ...                ...
```

I decided to find the mean of all these columns and save it into a new column, and then dropping these columns, so now instead of (attr1 - attr6) I'm left with...

```
avg_attr
5
6.5
7.166
...
```

The code for this is...

```
data['avg_attr'] = data[['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3', 'attr4', 'attr5', 'attr6']].mean(axis=1)

# Convert columns to 1-dimensional Series array
series = data.columns.to_series()

# Attribute data can be dropped because we already have the total mean.
data = data.drop(series["attr1":"attr6"], axis=1)
```

..when I did this I expected the algorithm's accuracy to not be impacted much by this change, plus I thought it had the added benefit of making my data look more clean. However, after applying this change the accuracy rate dropped by a little bit, why is this so? Is it because my algorithms are under-fitting the data now?

Also, on the side, is there anything I can do with these attributes to increase the accuracy rate?

Comment: Schwarzenegger and Einstein are no more different after averaging their physical and intellectual attractiveness. You think this is just a clean up? scnr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its natural that accuracy will decrease. You are taking `mean` but not correlation. In learning algorithm, internally `dependency` of value in one attribute is affecting the other. If you just average all attributes, how it can learn `dependency` of one on the other.

Another way you can drop the `columns/attributes` is by `dimensional reduction`. You need to find `correlation` and attributes having higher `correlation` can be dropped.

You can simply see using seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(test_data.corr())
```

You can visualize `highly correlated attributes` and can drop one by one. `Dimensional Reduction` is one of the ways to reduce information loss. I hope this explanation helps.

Answer (score 1):

Averaging can result in drop of accuracy, possibly due to underfitting as you mentioned. I would suggest trying out feature selection methods to choose suitable attribute.